# PHP, return class as object

Tags: php, class, function

I am testing the way writing PHP like js, and I wonder if this will be possible.

If say I have A, B function in Class C.

```
Class C{
   function A(){

   }
   function B(){

   }
}
$D = new C;

$D->A()->B(); // <- Is this possible and how??
```

In Js, we can simple write `like D.A().B();`

I tried `return $this` inside of `function A()`, didnt work.

Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is called fluent interface. You can implement it by making your class methods return themselves:

```
Class C{
   function A(){
        return $this;
   }
   function B(){
        return $this;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Returning `$this` inside the method `A()` is actually the way to go.
Please show us the code that supposedly didn't work (there probably was another error in that code).

Comment: Thank you very much!, and I found that I write something wrong...my bad to post the question..

Answer (score 5):

Its rather simple really, you have a series of mutator methods that all returns the original (or other) objects, that way you can keep calling functions.

```
<?php
class fakeString
{
    private $str;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->str = "";
    }

    function addA()
    {
        $this->str .= "a";
        return $this;
    }

    function addB()
    {
        $this->str .= "b";
        return $this;
    }

    function getStr()
    {
        return $this->str;
    }
}


$a = new fakeString();


echo $a->addA()->addB()->getStr();
```

This outputs "ab"

Returning `$this` inside the function allows you to call the other function with the same object just like jQuery does.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it and it worked

```
<?php

class C
{
  public function a() { return $this; }
  public function b(){ }
}

$c = new C();
$c->a()->b();
?>
```